# Tarski's fixed point theorem

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

My professor stated the following

"For every normal function $f \colon ON \to ON$ and for every ordinal $\beta$ there exist an ordinal $\gamma \ge \beta$ such that $f(\gamma)=\gamma$". (normal function is by definition a continuos and increasing function)

I'm trying to prove it but i don't able to prove one fact:

Let $\gamma=\bigcup \{f^n(\beta) \colon n \in \omega \}$, where $f^0(\beta)=\beta$. I have to prove that this is a limit ordinal...but arguin by absurd i don't find the way to arrive to a contradiction.

Comment: Your $\gamma$ does not need to be a limit ordinal: Consider the case where $f$ is the identity, and $\beta$ is a successor.

Comment: I think you mean *Veblen's fixed point theorem*.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Prove the following general statement: if $A$ is a set of ordinals whose order type is a limit ordinal, then $\sup A$ is a limit ordinal.

Comment: (My students had to prove that in the exam last semester :-))

Comment: I don't know how to prove it. I can prove that if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal then $sup \alpha = \alpha $ and $\bigcup \alpha = \alpha$...but I can't see the way to prove that $\gamma$ is limit.

Comment: **HINT:** An ordinal $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal if and only if for all $\alpha<\gamma$, $\alpha+1<\gamma$.

Comment: @andreasvr You cannot prove it. If you did, your proof is incorrect.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry but I don't understand where you want to arrive...Could you be more clear? I know the property that you write up, but however I don't know how to prove that $\gamma$ is limit.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Why you say it? I'm quite sure that the proof structured in that way is correct

Comment: @andreasvr: As Andres remarks, $\gamma$ doesn't *have* to be a limit ordinal. So you can't necessarily prove that $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal. But you can show that there *exists* a limit ordinal with this property.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ok. Maybe there is another way sure more general, but I think that the proof is correct. Isn't it? However, can you suggest me a book or a web page where I can find a proof of this Theorem? Thanks.